# I thought only usercontrol can navigate page inside a window frame in WPF app, is there any workarounds?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to jump to an error page if reading data fails, although I thought only if usercontrol activates(eg. button pressed) can successfully navigate, but is there anyway to do it automactally?

```
Window
|--Page
|--Page
```

1. Windows
2. --Page
3. --Page

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;

namespace Launcher
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for BootPage.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class BootPage : Page
    {
        public BootPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            readConfig();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bootError(1001); **//This works**
        }

        void readConfig()
        {

            string gamePath;
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load("e:\\bootstrap.xml");
            XmlNodeList boot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/config/startup/arkkdmca/boot");

            foreach (XmlNode node in boot)
            {
                try
                {
                    gamePath = node.SelectSingleNode("drive").InnerText + ":\\" + node.SelectSingleNode("directory").InnerText;
                    MessageBox.Show(gamePath);
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    gamePath = "null";
                    bootError(1001); **//This Failed**
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        void bootError(int errorCode)
        {
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new ErrorPage(errorCode));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say that line "fails", what do you mean *specifically*?  Does it throw an `Exception`, or does nothing happen?

Comment: It returned a "navigation System.NullReferenceException:" error